Is jquery 3.7.1 compatible with bootstrap 3?
I have an old Bootstrap 3 site built in 2017. I need to update to Bootstrap 5, but would like to update jquery in the meantime. Is jquery 3.7.1 compatible?

Have you tried it? It should be immediately apparent whether it does or doesn't. That said, there's really no reason it shouldn't. B3 has been compatible with jQuery 3 for a long time, and no breaking changes should occur within a major version.

Also, you haven't said which version of Bootstrap 3 you're using. It matters.

Also, you said you will upgrade to Bootstrap 5 so why this compatibility question? copy the whole site to the beta instance, upgrade to 5, update the library to 3.7.1, and test it.

Bootstrap 5 is designed to work without jquery - so boostrap 5 itself should work fine regardless of the version of jquery.   Whether your code is compatible with jquery or even Boostrap5 is another question...

According to the bower file of Bootstrap 3.4.1 you could update your jQuery, as long as your version is at least 1.9.1. Everything newer than that should be alright.
Out of curiosity I checked since when / which version jQuery 3 is supported by Bootstrap, and it turns out since version 3.3.37, which was released in 2016. (See this blog post)
